# Flask is not inserting values in DATABASE

Tags: python, mysql, flask

The following code is asking the system to enter each checkbox that has been filled in, and then displayed.
The display page is actually displaying the new registered rows, but when I make the same code SELECT * FROM at my terminal, the system does not show any. It looks like the database is temporary, because when i restart the flask app, the new rows disappear.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "toor", "msg_test")

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '31e1326344483068'

@app.route('/preenche', methods=['POST'])
def selecionarExames():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cursor = db.cursor()
        for t in request.form.getlist('check'):
            sql = "INSERT INTO exames_realizados (nomeExame, valores) VALUES ('{}', 0)".format(t)
            cursor.execute(sql)
        v = "SELECT * FROM exames_realizados"
        cursor.execute(v)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template('preenche.html', results=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: You might need to `commit` after each append or set `autocommit` on in connection settings.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **do not string format your query** - you are opening up your code to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, properly parameterize your query:

```
sql = """
    INSERT INTO 
        exames_realizados 
        (nomeExame, valores) 
    VALUES 
        (%s, 0)
"""
cursor.executemany(sql, request.form.getlist('check'))
```

Note how the query parameters are passed separately and the use of `.executemany()`.

As far as seeing the results of your insert query, commit your transaction to persist the changes:

```
db.commit()
```

Comment: It may also be worth adding the SQL models to a separate `models.py` file and importing it into the main routes code.

Comment: @w4g okay, you sure there are any values in the `request.form.getlist('check')`? Also, make sure to call `db.commit()` after `.executemany()`.